# Equivalence of definitions for completion

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For the settings on my question, take Atiyah's chapter on completions.

Basically we have two definitions of completness (Atiyah's sense, the canonical map $\phi:M\rightarrow \widehat{M}$ is an $A$-isomoprhism) and **complete in the usual sense**, this is, every Cauchy sequence converges.

I guess the first step is to give a topology on $\widehat{M}$. If we endow $\widehat{M}$ with the topology induced by the filtration $\{\widehat{M_i}\}$ (these are submodules of $\widehat{M}$), the map $\phi$ becomes continuous, hence Cauchy sequences in $M$ produce Cauchy sequences in $\widehat{M}$, so I would say that this is a natural candidate for the topology on $\widehat{M}$.

Are the two notions of completeness equivalent when using this topology on the completion? I want to say yes, yet Im not able to prove it.

Comment: Yes, they are! If I recall correctly, the proof starts by writing elements of $\hat{M}$ as infinite sequences $(a_0,a_1,\dotsc)$ of "compatible" elements of the modules you are taking the limit on (meaning $a_i \mapsto a_{i-1}$ for every $i$). You can then find an expansion for elements of $\hat{M}$ like the $p$-adic expansion of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. You may wish to have a look at section 1 of chapter 2 of Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory".

Comment: Here is  a link: http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/atm/caag1/balwant.pdf I hope that it will be helpful.